# How many repetitions does the loop

Tags: calculus, computational-complexity

Here is the following algorithm:

```
for(k=2; k<n; k=k^k)
```

I understand that I need to check when 
$n=k^k$.

But I'm stuck on $k=log_k(n)$

How many repetitions are performed by the loop?

Comment: Have you computed what $k$ is the first few passes through the loop?  It grows *very* rapidly.  I doubt there is a nice formula, but for any reasonable $n$ it will be no more than $3$

Comment: I know it grow very rapidly, but it's depends on "n", i guess that's will be log(log(n)) but i still don't know how to show it.

Answer (score 1):

After the first pass we have $k=2^2=4$  If $n$ is $3$ or $4$ there will be only one pass.
After the second pass we have $k=4^4=256$.  If $4 \lt n \le 256$ there will be two passes.
After the third we have $k=256^{256}$, which is enormous-about $600$ digits.  Only if $n$ is larger than this will there be a fourth pass.

I don't know of a nice function that can take $n$ and give back the number of passes.

Answer (score 1):

Notice that

$$2^2=4,4^4=256,256^{256}\approx3.2317\cdot10^{616}.$$

Needless to say, the next term is astronomical.

So you take little risk by saying zero to three iterations. (If $n$ is a 32 bits integer uniformly drawn, say three and you'll be right with probability $0.999999940$)

Answer (score 0):

We start with $k=2$. Since it is the first, let's call it $k_0$. We observe that:

$$k_0 = 2 = 2^1 = 2^{2^0}.$$

The next element of the sequence is:

$$k_1 = k_0^{k_0} = 2^2 = 2^{2^1}.$$

By continuing...

$$k_2 = k_3^{k_3} = (2^2)^{2^2} = 2^{2^3}.$$
$$k_3 = k_4^{k_4} = (2^{2^3})^{2^{2^3}} = 2^{2^{11}}.$$
$$k_4 = k_5^{k_5} = (2^{2^{11}})^{2^{2^{11}}} = 2^{2^{2059}}.$$

Let's introduce 
$s_i = \log_2 \log_2 k_i$ (i.e. $k_i = 2^{2^{s_i}})$. In our case, $s_0 = 0$, $s_1 = 1$, $s_2 = 3$, $s_3=11$, $s_4 = 2059$, ...

After a deep analysis of the showed calculation, it turns out that the $s$ sequence satisfies the following:

$$s_{i+1} = s_i + 2^{s_i},$$

with $s_0 = 0.$

Answer (score 0):

I looked for the number of repetitions, here is the answer I thought of:
$$
2^(2^k) = n 
$$
$$
log(2^(2^k)) = log(n)
$$
$$
2^klog(2)=log(n)
$$
$$
2^k=log(n)
$$

**$$
k=log(log(n))
$$**